# IntelliJ IDE (IDEA, PhpStorm, WebStorm): Shortcut for focusing Filter field in e.g. Change Log tool window

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, keymapping

Is there a shortcut for focusing the Filter box in tool windows, specifically the Change Log?

See the attached screenshot to know which field I'm talking about. I searched the net and key map, but found nothing like that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed at Jetbrains that unfortunately it's not possible yet: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5520523#5520523

Answer (score 0):

Just start typing with the focus inside the tool window. IDEA invokes the search automatically. To select the item, press Enter. To cancel, press Esc.

This feature is called [Tool Window Speed Search](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/speed-search-in-the-tool-windows.html).

Comment: I know the speed search, but unfortunately it doesn't work when you have `Change` tool window open and the active tab is `Log`. Log is only filtered when you type something in the `Filter` box.